# I18nManager.forceRtl(false) does not work in android

Tags: android, react-native

I want to disable forced-rtl in android device having (rtl-device-language) by calling:

```
await I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
RNRestart.Restart();
```

but the same code works when switching device-lang to (LTR-lang)

How can I disable RTL in an android device having (RTL-device-lang) ...

any suggestion ... any help ... anything ... is welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this in index.js file :

```
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
```

Comment: Excellent! ... works like a sharm ... Thank you!

Comment: yourWelcom , if u problem RTL in first load on android tell me to sending some code more :)

Comment: @MeisanSaba please send me your code for first load

Comment: import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store';

const store = configureStore();

I18nManager.forceRTL(false);

const Anbar = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Anbar);